# Monitor if TX+/- ethernet pins are sending data

Tags: transformer, ethernet, magnetics, monitor

I want to 'monitor' in a 'cheap way' if one device connected to Ethernet(100M-BaseT) is 'sending' packets or not. I only need a binary answer, I don't want to know the data that DUT transmits, only know if it is transmitting data or not.

I think that the best way is to monitor the TX+ and TX- pins of the DUT, but how?

I know that I cannot break the impedance of the cable, so it's correct to add another magnetics/transformer in the red square?

Ethernet is like a RS-485, so, theoretically, I can add another transformer while it has the same input impedance, right?
Thanks!

[image: Ethernet Monitor TX]

Comment: Which Ethernet you are talking about? 10M? 100M? 1000M?

Comment: Hi @Justme, I will update my question. It's 100M

Answer (score 2):

No, for your case there is no simple and cheap way to light up a LED when there is a data packet sent.

During the time when the 100M link is up, there is a constant transmission of IDLE pattern being transmitted, and it is scrambled with pseudorandom sequence.

Basically the simplest and cheapest option is to design (or buy) a two-port Ethernet switch and use the activity LEDs (or MDIO interface) it provides for monitoring data transmission.

Comment: wow.. I didn't know that. Just one question: Who is in charge of generating this IDLE pattern transmission? Imagine that windows hangs (blue screen) or linux also hangs. Does this IDLE pattern will be generated and transmitted?

Comment: The Ethernet PHY. So if you look at the link LEDs on the hanged PC or Ethernet switch, if link is up then it is a sign of idle pattern being present. So no, you can't sniff if the PC has hanged or not. I think you have a so-called XY problem, you have problem X and thought Y can solve it and are asking about solutions to Y. So is the original problem detecting if a PC has hanged?

Comment: Smart... Well, I'm trying to monitor multiple ways to check if a PC is hanged or not. One of them is to check if the PC is transmitting data over ethernet, so I want to find a cheap solution to know if a PC is sending data or not.

Comment: If it responds to ping at the IP address then it is not hanged. Make a program that listens for connections to it or periodically sends a broadcast packet to everyone so that it can be seen it is alive. Or play a continuous sound and detect it with a LED in the headphone socket. If the PC hangs, sound stops and LED turns off.

Comment: Last question about this IDLE pattern: It is sent periodically every 'x' ms? Imagine that there is no data sending over ethernet, so in this case, I will only see the IDLE pattern, but can I determine, using a microcontroller, if this 'data' is IDLE pattern or not? Example: IDLE pattern is sent every 100ms and it takes 2ms, so if there is voltage outside this pattern, means that there is data. If this is ok, can I add a magnet in the monitor device?

Comment: @Justme: "If the PC hangs, sound stops"  Not necessarily.  In fact, my experience would suggest "almost certainly not".  Sound is typically processed by a hardware timer transferring data from a buffer to a DAC, and that hardware timer can well keep running even if the PC main processor is hung.  It's very common to "hear" a PC hang (because the audio DAC starts looping on stuck buffer contents instead of receiving fresh blocks of data) far more quickly than you notice lack of response to mouse and keyboard input.

Comment: Idle pattern is constantly being sent if there is no ongoing data packet being sent. There are no gaps in the bit stream at all when the link is negotiated up. There is a constant stream of bits being sent at a rate of 125Mbps, although with MLT-3 line coding that has three amplitude levels.

Comment: Yep, constant sending of data is desirable as it allows both ends to stay synchronized and not having to restart clock recovery when the actual data comes.

Comment: Kotik, you'll really have to get used to the idea that the way you imagined you could supervise a network-attached device won't work, especially in times where network cards can offload some of the computational load of IP and even TCP, so that your network card might even respond to things without your operating system functioning. Not even to mention things like Intel Management Engine or Board Management Controllers, which are *designed* to communicate over network even when yot PC hangs. You'll want to ask the actual question that buggers you, not this "strawman" question.

Comment: Thanks to mmmm, Justme and Ben Voigt. Idea discarded. I will open another topic.